# Adding SwiftUI to UIKit, and navigation back to UIKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I have an existing application that is entirely UIKit, but it has been decided that new views should be added in SwiftUI. I am trying to add a new onboarding tutorial which is entirely images and was easy to write in SwiftUI.

```
import SwiftUI

struct OnboardingView: View {

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        
        ZStack {
            Image("Onboard 1")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .cornerRadius(25)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 10)
            
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                
                Button(action: {
                    //Navigate back to UIKit here
                }, label: {
                    Text("Exit Tutorial")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
                })
            }
            .frame(width: 120, height: 40)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 10)
            .offset(x: 70, y: 135)
            
        }
        Spacer()
        
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .frame(height: 40)
    }.navigationBarHidden(true)
}
}
```

I've added a new ViewController using storyboard and used a UIHostingController to successfully show the SwiftUI onboarding screens:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class OnboardingII: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: OnboardingView())

override func viewDidLoad() {
    openSwiftUIOnboardingScreen()
}

func openSwiftUIOnboardingScreen() {
    addChildViewController(hostingController)
    view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
    
    hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    hostingController.didMove(toParent: self) 
}

func endOnboarding() {
//Add navigation back to the main app here
print("End Onboarding called")
}
}
```

I've been looking for 3 days now and tried about a dozen different ways of navigating away from the SwiftUI onboarding process and back to the UIKit portion of the app (which is 99% of the app) but I've been unsuccessful in every attempt so far. Below are a few of the things that I've tried:

- Adding a segue to move back to the beginning of the app

  performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToBanner", sender: nil)

The rest of the app is managed by a navigation controller, and I've tried to get back in at several different points including the main navigation controller and two sub controller using segues identified on the storyboard, but in each case the crash error states that those views are not in the current window hierarchy.

- I have also tried the below code (one at a time):

  ```
  let viewController: UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestVC") as UIViewController

    self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    popoverPresentationController?.delegate?.popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover?(popoverPresentationController!)
    OnboardingII().dismiss(animated: false)
    OnboardingII().removeFromParentViewController()
    //BannerViewController.willMove(true)
    for child in BannerViewController().childViewControllers {child.removeFromParentViewController()}
    self.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
     hostingController.view.removeFromSuperview()
     hostingController.view.isHidden = true
     hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .blue
     hostingController.willMove(toParent: self)
     hostingController.removeFromParentViewController()
     hostingController.dismiss(animated: false)
     for child in hostingController.childViewControllers {child.removeFromParentViewController()}
     for child in hostingController.view.subviews {child.isHidden = true}
  ```

Thinking there must be some way to dismiss the UIHostingController (or hiding it) or anyway to get back to UIKit but I haven't had any success.

The strangest part is that if I change the newest ViewController on the Storyboard from .fullScreen to .automatic then I can swipe down to move back from SwiftUI to UIKit. This isn't the desired way to navigate as a button tap to move has been requested, but I haven't been able to replicated this functionality through code at all, I've tried reviewing rewind segues, but then I started to think that the swipe down to go back to the previous view is something else, but there should be a way to call it via code right?

Comment: Have you tried [`self.dismiss(animated:,completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) in `endOnboarding`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I just added self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil) into the endOnboarding function and there is no change, the SwiftUI screen remains. The print statement shows in the console, so I know the function is called, I just don't see any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation provides a step-by-step walkthrough for this scenario at https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Specifically, it ends with the following: "Now try out all the different interactions — PageView shows how UIKit and SwiftUI views and controllers can work together."

P.S.: From my experience, when there are multiple ways to achieve the same result in code, I would choose the option which is recommended by the framework's manufacturer (in this case - Apple), instead of relying on any third-party samples which differ in how they achieve that same result. Of course, there are exceptions to this rule-of-thumb that I adopted over the years, but mostly it works well.